# Weak convergence of Reversible and ergodic Markov chain on uncountable state space,

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

I think this may be a trivial question. But I could not find a proper reference due to my lack of knowledge. Suppose I have a Markov chain $X=(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ on the uncountable (but compact!) state space $\mathcal{S}$. It is known that $X$ admits a stationary distribution $\pi$.

Let $\mathbb{P}_{\pi}$ denote the canonical law of $X$ on the path space $\mathcal{S}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and assume that the probability preserving dynamical system $(\mathcal{S}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{P}_{\pi},\theta)$ is also ergodic where $\theta$ is the left-shift on $\mathcal{S}^{\mathbb{N}}$. By an application of pointwise Ergodic theorem and bounded convergence theorem, it is known that for $f\in C_b(\mathcal{S})$, we have
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_l)]=\int_{\mathcal{S}}f(y)\,\rm{d}\pi(y),\quad\text{ for }\ \pi \ \text{ a.e }\ x\in\mathcal{S}.
\end{equation}

Suppose we also know that $\pi$ reversible. By this I mean if $P(x,dy)$ is the probability transition kernel and $f,g\in C_B(\mathcal{S})$ then,
$$ \int_{\mathcal{S}} f(x)\int_{\mathcal{S}}g(y)P(x,dy)\,d\pi(x) = \int_{\mathcal{S}} g(x)\int_{\mathcal{S}}f(y)P(x,dy)\,d\pi(x).$$
My question is that if reversibility of $\pi$ is enough to get the strong convergence out of (1), i.e., does it hold,
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_n)] =\int_{\mathcal{S}}f\,\rm{d}\pi$$
for $\pi$ a.e $x$. I found the following reference (Theorem 2)  https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1962-68-02/S0002-9904-1962-10737-X/S0002-9904-1962-10737-X.pdf

which seems to suggest that at least $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_{2n})]$ exists for $\pi$ a.e $x$. I am not much familiar with the ergodic theory terminology.

**Update:** $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_{2n})]$ exists because,
if $T\,:\,L^2(\pi)\to L^2(\pi)$ is the Markov operator,
$$ Tf(x) := \int_{\mathcal{S}} f(y)\,P(x,dy), $$ then $T = T^*$ as $\pi$ is reversible. Also $T^nf(x) = \mathbb{E}_x[f(X_n)]$ for $f\in C_b(\mathcal{S})$. Thus by the Theorem 2, $\mathbb{E}_x[f(X_{2n})] = (T^n) (T^*)^nf(x)$ converges for $\pi$ a.e $x$.

As mentioned in the comment, I am ok with assuming that the chain is aperiodic.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: In their proof is there a hint that a limit exists only for the subsequence $X_{2n}$, but not for the original sequence? If the limit exists for the original sequence, I guess with $(1)$ it leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

From the convergence of $E_x f(X_{2n})$ you can deduce convergence of $E_x f(X_{2n+1})$ (by conditioning on $X_1$.) Convergence of   $E_x [f(X_{n})+f(X_{n+1})]$ also follows.

Without further assumptions, the convergence of $E_x f(X_n)$ may fail even on finite spaces, e.g., consider simple random walk on a bipartite graph (or a single edge) if $f$ takes value $1$ on one side and $0$ on the other.

Comment: I see your point @Yuval Peres. The problem in your example seems to arise from the periodicity of the walk. Fortunately, in my case, the chain is aperiodic. That is, the state space can not be decomposed into disjoint subsets into which the chain cycles through. Do you think this would be enough to guarantee the convergence of the whole sequence? I know this gives convergence for countable state space chain (assuming stationary distribution exists). But I'm not sure for the general state space case.

Comment: See The zero-two law:  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00531621

Comment: So I guess a sufficient condition for the weak convergence is that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dear @YuvalPeres, thank you very much for your answer and the reference. This solved one of my research problem and hopefully will result in publication. If it is alright with you, can I add your name in acknowledgement section of the preprint? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Sure, feel free to do so.